# Is the trackpad in the Mac Air connected to the keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

My wife spilled a little water on her Mac Air -- MD760ll/A which we got in August 2013 (just outside of any AppleCare warranty).  At first it was completely dead, but I removed the back and battery and sopped up the water and used a desiccant in a sealed box to dry it out even further.

Now it turns on, but the keyboard and trackpad don't work, however I can use the Mac with a USB keyboard/mouse.

Is the trackpad connected to the keyboard?  If that's the case is there the possibility that I would only need to replace the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. While the trackpad is *connected* to the keyboard, the trackpad and keyboard are separate parts and the trackpad may be fine, depending on where the water spilt and how quickly is was dried out.

If you have some experience with repairing electronics, get a 2013 MacBook Air keyboard assembly. It should include the keyboard and the aluminum panel that the keyboard's mounted in. You can buy just the keyboard, but having done that myself, I **strongly** recommend you buy the whole assembly, even though it's quite a bit more. You can buy the keyboard assembly on eBay (make sure you get a good one from a US seller) and find great repair guides on [iFixit](http://ifixit.com) (they also have an, albeit buggy, iOS app).

Of course, you could also go to a pro, if you don't feel comfortable with the repair yourself, but be prepared to pay hundreds of dollars.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your wife's MacBook Air; it's always frustrating when accidents like that happen. According to [this step in iFixit's teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Teardown/15042#s49089) of the 2013 Air, it appears that the trackpad is attached to the motherboard, instead of the keyboard:

[image: THere's a flat cable coming from the track pad to the motherboard in the middle of the frame]

Again, best of luck with the repair of the MacBook. If she can do without for a little while, waiting for a refresh in the line may be worthwhile, depending on the extent of water damage that isn't readily apparent (water damage can manifest weeks or even months after the fact.)